# English phonology for 'look'

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

. . . when we look at . . . [wən-wi-**lʊk**-ət]     [[audio source]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/133)

The pronunciation in the audio for [luk] seems to be heard [lək]. If I hear right, does [[l] pull the [ʊ] towards schwa sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology), and so [ʊ] assimilate into [ə]?

Comment: I found the audio clip a bit hard to understand, but I will note that the speaker was using British English. The pronunciation between British and American English of words such as "look" and "book" is different. I'm not sure which you're trying to learn, but it's something worth pointing out I think :) I'm sure you'll get an answer soon-I'm not great with the pronunciation symbols, so I'll just +1 and leave this question to someone who knows better than I!

Comment: He's not an English but a Kiwi professor.

Comment: What @Listenever said. The guy's speaking quickly, in typically "clipped" Antipodean style. But probably most Anglophones of whatever dialectal persuasion would tend towards a schwa there, with the effectively "parenthetical" set phrase *but when you look at*.

Comment: If he's NZ I have to withdraw my answer, which is irrelevant. My apologies for misleading you. May I trouble you to unaccept it, so I can delete it?

Comment: @StoneyB, He's a professor in Aukland University, yet I don't know what nationality he has. This audio is from his interview with BBC. If he's NZ or not, your explanation itself was very useful and educational for me. And copied into by personal blog for consulting once in a while. I'll check unaccept, but I hope it will be existed or you may correct for better knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: Hah! Googled the quote, got the name and [Here he is!](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/english-phonology-for-look). Not conclusive, but BSc Univ.Ireland-Galway and PhD Univ.Ireland-Cork. I'll withdraw my request. Thirty years of stage work were not entirely wasted after all.

Comment: @StoneyB, Thank you again. And I wish you check the link for 'Here he is!'

Comment: Oops! [HERE](http://www.marine.auckland.ac.nz/uoa/dr-mark-costello) he actually is.

Comment: @StoneyB The first link was a nice joke: I clicked on it, and I found myself back to this very question. `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I believe what we're hearing is a dialect. I read the sound on this as [lʌk], or at least closer to [lʌk] than [lʊk]. It's a very brief excerpt, but I'm pretty sure it's Irish.  I once had to perform a part in the Dublin dialect (although it was almost forty years ago!) and I remember that pronunciation; and Wikipedia ([Hiberno_English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English#Pronunciation)) says:

> In some varieties, speakers make no distinction between the [ʌ] in putt and the [ʊ] in put, pronouncing both as the latter. Bertz (1975) found this merger in working-class Dublin speech, and a fluctuation between merger and distinction in General Dublin English (quoted in Wells 1982). Nevertheless, even for those Irish people who, say, have a different vowel sound in put and cut, pairs such as putt and put, **look and luck** may be pronounced identically. [My emphasis]

This is of course the **opposite** shift from that we're hearing; but this is an educated speaker, and it may represent a hypercorrection.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way of pronouncing look would be /lʊk/. Note however that with some regional accents, this can change; for example, some UK accents expand the vowel to produce something closer to /lu:k/.

I'm not sure I've ever heard someone pronounce *look* as /lək/, though. I think in your audio example, it's still actually /lʊk/; it's just that the speaker is speaking quite quickly, making it a bit hard to make out.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it sounds rather [lɔk] than [lʌk].

*Look* cognates to a Proto-Germanic root, *lōkōnan, which is pronounced [ˈlɔː.kɔː.nɑ̃]. So there's no surprise speakers of different dialects of English pronounce *look* with [ɔ].

Also, *shwa* [ə] is quite popular as well. Listen how it is pronounced in [The Beatles' "While My Guitar Gently Weeps"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3RYvO2X0Oo), for example.

Comment: Do you mean 'pronounced' rather than 'spelled'?