# Might any native pronounce have, had, as [hev],[hed]?

Tags: pronunciation

> ... had [hӕd]  ... have had [hӕv] [hӕd] ... have [hӕv] ... have [həv] ...
>   [(audio source)](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/137)

I hear the sounds of have and had as above. After some pronunciation guides from an expert [StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/english-phonology-for-look) and [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/pron/sounds/)'s pronunciation tips, I can hear the second examples as [hӕv] [hӕd]. If I haven't got the chances I might have transcribed them as /hev hed/. Might any native pronounce *have*, and *had*, respectively as /hev/, and /hed/?

Comment: Thanks for the bow, but I'm not an expert, merely an interested amateur with some practical experience!

Comment: I believe people in New Zealand do due to their accent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three suggestions as to accents with this sort of pronunciation, South African, New Zealand, and possibly the bit that's either the north of England or south of Scotland which I think would be called Geordie.

I'm not absolutely sure as to the last, but the accents of the first two definitely carry that inflection, imho.

Comment: Good call. Wikipedia sv [Geordie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geordie#Phonology): “/æ/ specifically in the words had, have, has and having is pronounced as [ɛ].” sv [South African English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_English#Vowels): “[/æ /] in Broad is often raised to [ɛ], so that /æ/ encroaches on /ɛ/ for some speakers. A good example of this is South Africa sounds more like South Efrica.” And a table sv [New Zealand English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand_English#Phonology) gives /ɛ/ for the trap vowel (æ).

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you. I was concerned as to the pc-ness of calling out accents, so I'm relieved they've been called out officially. ... and I am definitely going to have to learn this IPA stuff.

Answer (score 4):

As a native of the eastern US, I usually pronounce the phrase *have had* with more stress on *had*, with consequent shifting of the pronunciation toward [hev][haed], and even dropping the *ha* as in *I've had a good day*.  But some situations require stress on *have*, and then the vowels both have the [ae] pronunciation, as in *I **have** had better days!*

I wouldn't pronounce *have* or *had* with [e] if it is the main verb, but I can't be sure that this is the universal (or US-ual) pronunciation.

Comment: I think you've finally answered [**this**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87645/can-i-use-us-american-to-disambiguate-american-if-not-what-can-i-use) question.

Comment: @StoneyB -- thank you; I hadn't seen that.  (And I do apologize for the totally nonstandard usage.  Or US-age.  It was just too obvious to resist,, albeit naughty.)

Comment: I intend to adopt it, even in the face of universal disapproval.

Answer (score 0):

When "had" is used for past perfect tense (i.e., "had jumped", "had looked", or even "had had") it's pronounced with either a short "e" sound or maybe a schwa sound rather than a short "a" sound.

Something similar applies as well for perfect and future perfect tenses with the word "have". For example, "will have been": "have" is not pronounced with a short "a", but rather a short "e" or schwa.